# Android Kotlin AlertDialog wrap_content not working

Tags: android, kotlin, view, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create a view for use in an alert and I can't get wrap_content to work in an alert dialog.  I've tried both a LinearLayout and a ConstraintLayout with the same results.

I've tried several things including these [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604242/android-dialog-wrap-content-not-working) :

```
val selectView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.font_size_sel, null)
val builder = androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
builder.setView(selectView)
val dialog = builder.create()
dialog.window!!
    .setLayout(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
dialog.show()
```

and

```
val selectView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.font_size_sel, null)
val builder = androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
builder.setView(selectView)
val dialog = builder.create()
dialog.setOnShowListener {
    dialog.window?.setLayout(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
}
dialog.show()
```

and I've from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258876/set-width-of-custom-dialog-to-wrap-content-android/35145585) I've tried:

```
val selectView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.font_size_sel, null)
val builder = androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
builder.setView(selectView)
val dialog = builder.create()
val lp = dialog.window!!.attributes
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
dialog.window!!.attributes = lp
dialog.show()
```

I've tried putting the dialog.show() both before and after setting wrap_content in the code above.

I've tried both ConstraintLayout and LinearLayout with the same results.

Both the layout and the textview have wrap_contents for both the width and height.

This is what the design window from AndroidStudio's layout editor says the window should look like:
[image: Android Studio layout editor image]

And this is a snapshot of the device with the debugger's "show padding..." turned on.
[image: device snapshot]

I'm stuck.  Any ideas out there??  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Steve S.

Comment: You need to set width and height of dialog window to match parent
and textView width and height to wrap content

Comment: @Vojin Purić, if I understand you correctly, hat makes the dialog take over the whole screen, right?  I would like the dialog floating in the middle of the screen occupying no more space than it needs.